# Having difficulty with statistics problem (Stem-leaf) diagram

Tags: statistics

I never used this website before, but if anyone could help me with this then that will be great. Also, if I tagged my question in the wrong topic, please point me in the right direction as well.

What numbers represents following Stem-and-Leaf Diagram? Stems: 2, 3, 4 Leaf: 0,3,5,6: 1, 4, 6: 7,9

A. 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 3, 4, 9, 5, 6, 6

B. 0, 3, 5, 6, 1, 4, 6, 7, 9

C. 20, 22, 24, 25, 31, 33, 34, 39, 41, 42

D. 20, 23, 25, 26, 31, 34, 36, 47, 49

Comment: In general, the leaves represent the least significant digits of the numbers, the stems represent the higher order digits. For example the stem 2 with leaves 0,3,5,6 represents the numbers 20, 23, 25, 26. if the leaves represent the units digit.

Answer (score 1):

If your diagram looks like the following:

\begin{align}
2 &\mid 0\ 3\ 5\ 6 \\
3 &\mid 1\ 4\ 6 \\
4 &\mid 7\ 9
\end{align}

Then the stems are the tens digits and the leaves that appear to the right of each stem are the units digit for that stem.

So, from the top stem, we get $20, 23, 25, 26$. From the middle stem, we get $31,34,36$. From the bottom stem, we get $47, 49$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little trick of elimination since it's a multiple choice. **A** and **B** are definitely out since they do not take into account the **stems**.

Now take a look at the first stem, which is a $2$. The leafs of the stems, $0,3,5,6$ would automatically mean that you should see the values $20, 23, 25$ and $26$ in the dataset. This automatically rules out **C**.

How can I be sure? Look at **C** again and observe how it contains $22$. This should indicate that $2$ has to be a leaf in the *first* stem. Since that is not there, I can safely eliminate it, which leaves with **D**.

It seems to me like an examination question, and hence I answered it with that strategy in mind.

Answer (score -1):

When making a stem plot by hand, you should always specify the position of the decimal point
at the head of a stem plot. Here are examples using R (first) and Minitab to show how this may be handled in software output.

```
 x = c(20, 23, 25, 26, 31, 34, 36, 47, 49)
 stem(x)

   The decimal point is 1 digit(s) to the right of the |

   2 | 0356
   3 | 146
   4 | 79

 y = x/10
 y
 ## 2.0 2.3 2.5 2.6 3.1 3.4 3.6 4.7 4.9
 stem(y)

## The decimal point is at the |

   2 | 0356
   3 | 146
   4 | 79
```

Sometimes, the stem is 'split'. Then leaves 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 appear
opposite the first mention of the stem number, and 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
appear opposite the second.  Each software package has
its own rules about splitting, which can be overridden if you like.

In Minitab output, the left column accumulates
the number of observations from the top or bottom, and the
number in parentheses signifies the number of observations
on the line that contains the median.

```
 MTB > set c10
 DATA> 20, 23, 25, 26, 31, 34, 36, 47, 49
 DATA> end
 MTB > stem c10

 Stem-and-leaf of C10  N  = 9
 Leaf Unit = 1.0

  2   2  03
  4   2  56                # Notice 4 + 2 + 3
 (2)  3  14                # gives the total
  3   3  6                 # sample size n = 9
  2   4
  2   4  79

 MTB > stem c10;
 SUBC> incr 10.  # subcommand overrides default splitting

 Stem-and-Leaf Display: C10 

 Stem-and-leaf of C10  N  = 9
 Leaf Unit = 1.0

  4   2  0356
 (3)  3  146
  2   4  79
```

Suppose that, on average, a huge international construction company experiences 35
industrial accidents a day worldwide. Here is a simulation in R of the number
of accidents a day (assuming a Poisson distribution) over 100 days, with results shown in a stem plot. Notice that R 'splits the stem' here to
keep lines of leaves from getting too long. Numbers of accidents
were 21, 24, 25, ..., 45, 46, 46.

```
 w = rpois(100, 35)   # simulates 'fake' data
 stem(w)

 ## The decimal point is 1 digit(s) to the right of the |

 2 | 14
 2 | 5555566677777888888899
 3 | 001222222223334444444
 3 | 55555566666666777778888888899999
 4 | 00000111112222233334
 4 | 566

 length(w); mean(w);  var(w)
 ## 100           # n
 ## 34.71         # sample mean
 ## 33.86455      # sample variance
```

A typical result with Poisson data is for the sample mean
and variance to be roughly the same number.